# Add Expire Headers in php can't make it work

Tags: php, performance, .htaccess, yslow

I have **Yslow** add-on installed

[image]

When I checks my application in Yslow I get **Add Expires headers** which I don't know

[image]

I searched for relevant questions in SO and also Google I found this method appropriate

```
<?
    header("Expires:".gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T', time() + 3600));
    header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    ob_start();
    session_cache_limiter('public');
    session_start();
?>
<html>
```

But still it shows me same

As i am newbie I don't know much about .htaccess

Please help me improve applications performance

Thanks in advance

**Wazzy**

Comment: Get firebug (or any other tool) and see that there are expire headers.

Comment: Well asked by the way, nice use of images. +1

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That will only set it for your page content and not things like images and css files, i noticed on your screenshot it says 42 files, presumably these are your images, css, js etc.

Try this in your .htaccess file, note this will only work if you have `mod_expires` and `mod_headers` enabled in Apache:

```
<ifModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive On
  ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 1 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 604800 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 216000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 216000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 216000 seconds"  
</ifModule>

<ifModule mod_headers.c>
  <filesMatch "\\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public"
  </filesMatch>
  <filesMatch "\\.(css)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
  </filesMatch>
  <filesMatch "\\.(js)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=216000, private"
  </filesMatch>
  <filesMatch "\\.(xml|txt)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=216000, public, must-revalidate"
  </filesMatch>
  <filesMatch "\\.(html|htm|php)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=1, private, must-revalidate"
  </filesMatch>
</ifModule>
```

Comment: +1 for quick reply.Thanks for the answer.I will surely accept your answer if i will not get more better answer than this.This doen't mean that you are not correct just waiting for more reply.Thanks and regards.Wazzy